# observeEvent for several ui elements

Tags: r, shiny

**Problem**

On my UI I want to have a checkbox, which controls whether a certain slider is enabled. I use `toggleState` from `library(shinyjs)` to do so. I add an `observeEvent` and if the checkbox is clicked, the state is toggled - see attached example. So far so good. I could now copy paste the `observeEvent` for all checkbox / slider pairs, but I was wondering whether I can do something smarter. Is there a possibility to write a "parameterized" `observeEvent` function, which fires if any of the check boxes is clicked and uses the id of the checkbox clicked to determine which slider to activate?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
   fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, checkboxInput("id1.ckb", "Click to activate Slider 1")),
      column(width = 6, sliderInput("id1.sld", "Choose:", min = 1, max = 30, value = 2,
                                    step = 1))       
   ),
   fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, checkboxInput("id2.ckb", "Click to activate Slider 2")),
      column(width = 6, sliderInput("id2.sld", "Choose:", min = 1, max = 30, value = 2,
                                step = 1))       
   ),
   fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, checkboxInput("id3.ckb", "Click to activate Slider 3")),
      column(width = 6, sliderInput("id3.sld", "Choose:", min = 1, max = 30, value = 2,
                                step = 1))       
   ),
   fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, checkboxInput("id4.ckb", "Click to activate Slider 4")),
      column(width = 6, sliderInput("id4.sld", "Choose:", min = 1, max = 30, value = 2,
                                step = 1))       
   )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$id1.ckb, {
      toggleState("id1.sld")
   })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect use case for modules and loops:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

boxSliderUI <- function(id, label="Click to activate Slider") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, checkboxInput(ns("ckb"),label)),
      column(width = 6, sliderInput(ns("sld"), "Choose:", min = 1, max = 30, value = 2,
                                    step = 1))       
    ))
}

boxSlider <- function(input,output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$ckb, {
    toggleState("sld")
  })

  value <- reactive(input$sld)

  return(value)
}


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  lapply(1:4,function(i) boxSliderUI(paste0("id",i),paste0("Click to activate Slider ",i))),
  verbatimTextOutput("return")
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  vals <- lapply(1:4,function(i) callModule(boxSlider,paste0("id",i)))

  output$return <- renderPrint(lapply(1:4,function(i) vals[[i]]()))

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

edit: added label parameter to UI so I could dynamically name the label

---

edit2: Added a return statemend in the module and showed how you can extract the values from the sliders, since with modules that isn't totally straightforward.

Comment: Wow, amazing! Learned a lot, need to read some docs now to understand the functionality, but you nailed it - thanks! +1

Comment: I made a somewhat important edit FYI so now you can see how to actually use the values from the sliders in the modules